# Is it acceptable to use optional package resolution for build time only dependencies?

Tags: osgi

I have a build time dependency on the package `javax.annotation[2.0,3)`. That's because I use Guava and the `@Nullable` annotation in some `Predicate` implementations.

These, being annotations, are just build time dependencies, so is it acceptable to mark them as optional, and not include them in my run time distribution (to save space where possible)?

```
Import-Package: javax.annotation;resolution:=optional;version="[2.0,3)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work fine. You can alternatively completely omit the import.